# Store large text corpus in Python

Tags: python, nlp, corpus

I am trying to build a large text corpus from the [Wikipedia dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/). 
I represent every article as a *document* object consisting of:

- the original text: a string
- the preprocessed text: a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a (stemmed) word and the position of the word in the original text
- some additional information like title and author

I am searching for an efficient way to save these objects to disk. The following operations should be possible:

- adding a new document
- accessing documents via an ID
- iterate over all documents

It is not necessary to remove an object once it was added.

I could imagine the following methods:

- **Serializing each article to a separate file, for example using pickle:** the downside here are probably lots of operating system calls
- **Store all documents to a single xml file or blocks of documents to several xml files:** Storing the list that represents the preprocessed document in xml format uses a lot of overhead and I think its quite slow to read a list from xml
- **Using an existing package for storing the corpus:** I found [Corpora](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Corpora/1.0) package, which seems to be very fast and efficient, but it only supports storing strings plus a header including metadata. Simply putting the preprocessed text into the header makes it run incredibly slow.

What would be a good way to do this? Maybe a package for that purpose, which i have not found until now?

Comment: Why not use a database for that? You can use both sql/nosql. They all give you what you are looking for, and you don't really need to reinvent here anything. Since you said you are looking at your articles as documents I would advise to think about nosql (http://elastic.co for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wonder why i have not thought about this myself. I am going to use [CodernityDB](http://labs.codernity.com/codernitydb) for my project and see how it works out.

Comment: FWIW, I created a database to help me in my NLP research https://github.com/amirouche/hoply/